# Add menu entry to generic right-click menu?

Tags: python, interface, properties, operator

I can't find a way to append/prepend an operator to blenders generic "right-click" menu. When looking into the source of `interface_handlers.c` it seems the operators of the menu itself are *hard coded*, furthermore I can not find any *draw* method in `/scripts/startup/bl_ui/` folder so I guess the menu is not exposed to the API, correct?

[image]

**Q:** Is there any way to add an entry to the menu and *ideally assign a custom value to the active property under the mouse cursor*?

Comment: I was trying to do this a while ago, I was told by a developer in #blendercoders that this was not possible. as you have stated, the menu is hard coded in C, and not accessible by python.

Comment: We could try to move this menu to Python. Another alternative would be to append a Python menu to the C menu (that needs to be done from C though).

Comment: Talked with Campbell about it, patched Blender locally already and it works great...am preparing a patch for 2.79 and will submit it soon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of this [commit](https://developer.blender.org/D2303), thanks to @p2or and @brecht, the [bpy.ops.ui.copy_data_path_button()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.ui.html#bpy.ops.ui.copy_data_path_button) operator now allows to copy the *full data-path* of the **active property under the mouse cursor** to the clipboard  which can be used to assign custom values to the active property (only available in latest versions).

[image]

Simplified version of the provided example in the patch (integers only):

```
import bpy

class MouseCursorPropertyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "screen.active_int_property_add"
    bl_label = "Adjust active mouse cursor integer property"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    my_int = bpy.props.IntProperty(default=100)
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bpy.ops.ui.copy_data_path_button.poll()

    def execute(self, context):      
        
        # get the data path
        bpy.ops.ui.copy_data_path_button()
        path = context.window_manager.clipboard
        
        # get full data path
        bpy.ops.ui.copy_data_path_button(full_path=True)
        full_path = context.window_manager.clipboard
        
        # split path in class and property
        rna, prop = context.window_manager.clipboard.rsplit('.', 1)
            
        # set attribute if type is integer
        if type(eval(full_path)) is int:
            rna_eval = (eval(rna))
            value = getattr(rna_eval, prop)
            setattr(rna_eval, prop, value + self.my_int)
            self.report({"INFO"}, "{} set to {}".format(prop, value + self.my_int))
        else:
            print (type(eval(full_path)))
            self.report({"INFO"}, "{} is not an integer property".format(prop))
            
        return {'FINISHED'}
    

addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MouseCursorPropertyOperator)

    # handle the keymap
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Screen')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(MouseCursorPropertyOperator.bl_idname, type='Q', value='PRESS', shift=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister():

    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MouseCursorPropertyOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

---

And as of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/D2612), thanks to @plasmasolutions you can now add an operator to the menu:

[image]

Provided example of the patch:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Header, Menu, Panel

def dump(obj, text):
    print('-'*40, text, '-'*40)
    for attr in dir(obj):
        if hasattr( obj, attr ):
            print( "obj.%s = %s" % (attr, getattr(obj, attr)))

class TestOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.test_op"
    bl_label = "Execute a custom action"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        if hasattr(context, 'button_pointer'):
            btn = context.button_pointer 
            dump(btn, 'button_pointer')

        if hasattr(context, 'button_prop'):
            prop = context.button_prop
            dump(prop, 'button_prop')

        if hasattr(context, 'button_operator'):
            op = context.button_operator
            dump(op, 'button_operator')     
            
        return {'FINISHED'}

# This class has to be exactly named like that to insert an entry in the right click menu
class WM_MT_button_context(Menu):
    bl_label = "Add Viddyoze Tag"

    def draw(self, context):
        pass

def menu_func(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.separator()
    layout.operator(TestOp.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.types.WM_MT_button_context.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.WM_MT_button_context.remove(menu_func)

classes = (
    TestOp,
    WM_MT_button_context,
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
    register()
```

*(Note: In Blender versions 3.3 and above,* `WM_MT_button_context` *must be changed to* `UI_MT_button_context_menu`).

Comment: I'm really glad that you posted this example here as I didn't have a clue that that's already working ...  but it's not the answer to the question. The question is not only targeted at changing a value under the cursor but also at having one / several own items in the menu... and this is currently not possible. I'll patch Blender soon to allow that though.

Comment: @plasmasolutions Now that Blender 2.79 is released and has this functionality, could you add an example of how to do it?