# How to copy the full data path of a property to the clipboard?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I right click on the cube Z location, then select "copy data path". When I paste that into the console I find the word `location`. Why doesn't it paste `bpy.data.objects['cube'].location[2]`?

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place the cursor over a property and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy the full RNA data path of that property to the *clipboard* eg. `bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location[2]`.

The hotkey calls [`bpy.ops.ui.copy_data_path_button(full_path=True)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.ui.html#bpy.ops.ui.copy_data_path_button) operator:

[image]

Somehow related: [Add menu entry to generic right-click menu?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/64951/31447)

Comment: Carpal tunnel syndrome alert !