# Animate keyframes with python

Tags: python, animation

I can see how to use-

object.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=10)

to keyframe an object's location, but how can I find the data path value for other parameters?

Eg I want to keyframe the start and end bevel mapping value on a curve what should I put instead of "location"?

Thanks,

Owen

Comment: Rightclick on the Field and choose copy datapath

Comment: Right Click and choose copy datapath only works if you don't want the full path.  See [this discussion](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/0wbbbc/?sorting=hot)  If you need the full datapath, then see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176044/how-to-copy-the-full-data-path-of-a-property-to-the-clipboard)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks all